# Caesar cipher in C won't work

Tags: c, encryption

I've got an assignment from school to make a program that will encrypt and decrypt a text. I have to use this declaration:

```
int encrypted(char *plainText, int arrLength, int key, char *cipherText);
```

For the moment i can make the caesar cipher work when i have the for-loop (the one i show in myfunctions.c) in main.c, but when i write the for-loop in another file (myfunctions.c) with the declaration above, it compiles and runs, but it seems like the for-loop in myfunctions.c doesn't executes like it should.

Here is my main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "myfunctions.h"

int main(){
    int key, arrLength, menu=0;
    char plainText[100], cipherText[100], result[100];


    printf("Encrypt\n");
    printf("Enter your key (1-25): ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    printf("Write the word or sentece you want to encrypt: ");
    fgets(plainText, 100, stdin);
    arrLength=strlen(plainText);
    encrypted(plainText, arrLength, key, result);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

myfunctions.c:

```
#include "myfunctions.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int encrypted(char *plainText, int arrLength, int key, char *cipherText){
int result = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++)
{

    // encryption
    result = (*plainText + key);

    // wrapping after Z for uppercase letters
    if (isupper(*plainText) && (result > 'Z'))
    {
        result = (result - 26);
    }

    // wrapping after z for lowercase letters
    if (islower(*plainText) && (result > 'z'))
    {
        result = (result - 26);
    }


    if (isalpha(*plainText))
    {
        printf("%c", result);
    }


    else
    {
        printf("%c", *plainText);
    }

}
return 1;
}
```

myfunctions.h

```
#ifndef myfunctions_h
#define myfunctions_h

int encrypted(char *plainText, int arrLength, int key, char *cipherText);

#endif
```

Comment: What does "can't get it to work" mean? In the main file do you call the function? If so please add tat to the question.

Comment: What do you mean with " i can't get it to work?" doesn't compile? Also show the .h file

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation, hope you understand better now!

Comment: Note that `fgets` retains the `newline` which you can remove with `plainText [ strcspn(plainText, "\r\n") ] = 0;`

Comment: @pottsork, don't worry ;). You can make it even better by adding the actual output and what did you expected!

Comment: Note: `sentece` --> `sentence`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You forgot to inclement `plainText` in the for loop in `encrypted()`.
- Be careful not to have `fgets()` read newline character **before** the plain text.

Try this `main` function

```
int main(){
    int key, arrLength, menu=0;
    char keyText[100],plainText[100], cipherText[100], result[100];


    printf("Encrypt\n");
    printf("Enter your key (1-25): ");
    fgets(keyText, 100, stdin);
    sscanf(keyText, "%d", &key);
    printf("Write the word or sentece you want to encrypt: ");
    fgets(plainText, 100, stdin);
    arrLength=strlen(plainText);
    encrypted(plainText, arrLength, key, result);

    return 0;
}
```

and changing the loop `for(int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++)`
to `for(int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++, plainText++)`

Comment: This worked! I will study the code to learn what i did wrong! Thank you Mike!

Comment: Good point about the `newline` **before** the text (as well as after).